# Proper way to handle authentication

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-security

I have read a lot of different examples on how to implement authentication in an Angular app. I am using [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) as a (No-)Backend.

Users should only see any content of my app, once they are logged in. If they are logged out, all they can see is `/auth/login` and `/auth/register`. Currently, I have the following solution which works. But:

1) I am not sure whether this is bullet-proof because...

2) ... when I open `/home` manually while NOT logged in, I correctly get redirected to `/auth/login` but the `HomeCtrl` gets executed anyway. No sensitive data is exposed because no data is returned from the Backend, but there must be a way to NOT execute the controller at all if I am logged out?

3) Everytime I expose sensitive data, do I have to check inside my controller if the user is authenticated over and over again?

Bonus question: How do I redirect to `/home` after successful login? Currently, inside my AuthService I do `$location.path('home');` on successful login, but this doesn't account for the state?!

My app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.controllers'])

.run(function($rootScope, $location, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {     

  /**
   * AuthService.isLoggedIn() returns TRUE or FALSE
   * depending on whether user authenticated successfully 
   * against the Firebase backend
   */

    // redirect to login 
    if (!AuthService.isLoggedIn() && to.name !== 'auth.register') {
      $location.path('/auth/login');
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('auth', {
      url: "/auth",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/auth-tabs.html",
      controller: 'AuthCtrl'
    })

    .state('auth.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'login-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/auth-login.html'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('auth.register', {
      url: '/register',
      views: {
        'register-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/auth-register.html'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

});
```

Comment: [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) has a working router/login system, as well as a drop-in module you can use with ngRoute. You should be able to grab some ideas there (or just use it).

Answer (score 1):

The way I've implemented it is by handling a `401` http server response, because I don't want to worry about checking for the user authentication state, I prefer letting the server handle that. That being said.

Documentation on `$urlRouter.sync()` specifies that if you prevent the default event, you may manually trigger the `succesChange`

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
  .run(function($rootScope, $urlRouter) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(evt) {
      // Halt state change from even starting
      evt.preventDefault();
      // Perform custom logic
      var meetsRequirement = ...
      // Continue with the update and state transition if logic allows
      if (meetsRequirement) $urlRouter.sync();
    });
});
```

[$urlRouter documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.%24urlRouter)